# Why is my try catch method not showing the error message I wrote for an entered String instead of integer? (Java)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, try-catch

```
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Stage 4: Enter an integer between 5 and 500:");
IntEntry = keyedInput.nextInt();

if(IntEntry > 5 && IntEntry < 500)
{
    System.out.println("You will go to stage 5.");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        while(IntEntry < 5 || IntEntry > 500)
        {
            System.out.println("Try Again. Enter an integer that is between 5 and 500 characters long. “z”.");
            IntEntry = keyedInput.nextInt();
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Try Again. Enter an integer between 5 and 500:.");
    }
}
```

Above is the code in which I'm trying to get a valid integer that the user inputs between 5 and 500. If the user enters a *string* rather than an *integer*, the program should output a message for the user using the *try-catch* method. The *try-catch* method isn't working for me and it outputs an error message. Can someone tell me why the *try-catch* method isn't working in my code?

Comment: What code do you think is throwing the NFE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch a `InputMismatchException` and not a `NumberFormatException` when using [`Scanner#nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--). Additionally, your first time using `nextInt()` is not within a *try-catch* block. Furthermore, your code does not loop anymore when you are catching the exception later. You can use a *do-while* loop and a flag (e.g. `valid`) to do this cleanly. Only when the integer can be parsed and is within range, the flag is set. Consequently, the loop continues until the user enters a valid integer that is within range. Here is a complete example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Stage 4: Enter an integer between 5 and 500:");

int intEntry;
boolean valid = false;
do {
    try {
        intEntry = scanner.nextInt();
        if (intEntry > 5 && intEntry < 500) {
            valid = true; // set flag to leave loop
        } else {
            System.out.println("Integer out of range. Try Again. Enter an integer between 5 and 500:");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not parse integer. Try again. Enter an integer between 5 and 500:");
        scanner.next(); // clear invalid token
    }
} while (!valid);

System.out.println("You will go to stage 5.");
```

Comment: @Newusersda I just updated the answer. This code is tested and should work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The [javadoc of Scanner's `nextInt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) states that it throws an `InputMismatchException`. Not a `NumberFormatException`. (You're confused with `Integer.parseInt`).

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Stage 4: Enter an integer between 5 and 500:");

try{        
     IntEntry = keyedInput.nextInt();
     if(IntEntry > 5 && IntEntry < 500)
        {
            System.out.println("You will go to stage 5.");
        }
     else
        {
            try
            {
                while(IntEntry < 5 || IntEntry > 500)
                {
                    System.out.println("Try Again. Enter a string that is between 5 and 15 characters long, and does not contain the letter “z”.");
                    IntEntry = keyedInput.nextInt();
                }
            }catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Try Again. Enter a string that is between 5 and 15 characters long, and does not contain the letter “z”.");
            }
    }
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Try Again. Enter a string that is between 5 and 15 characters long, and does not contain the letter “z”.");
                }
```